# Install .deb Package Error (dpkg error) Debian/Ubuntu machine

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg, debian

I've been confronting an issue while installin .deb package on debian and ubuntu machine. i have tried various way but not able to install it. it throws me an error below. I' trying to install snowagent on linux based machine.

[image: dpkg error message]

Not only this I've also tried following command `sudo apt-get install agent.deb` but each time when i run this command on shell it prompts me following error.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package agent.deb
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'agent.deb'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'agent.deb'
```

When i use `dpkg -s agent` its successful installation it prompts me status `Install ok half-configured`

NOTE: I've downloaded .deb file from azure blob first in VM first.

Comment: Standard things to try at this point are `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and `sudo apt install -f`.

Comment: No success , I've tried this . it throws me an error dpkg: error processing package snowagent (--install):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 snowagent

Comment: `sudo apt install ./agent.deb`

Comment: Apparently the post-installation script contains something which fails. Without knowing what's in there I cannot tell, but try reading `/var/lib/dpkg/info/snowagent.postinst` and see.